# Rollup can't see named export from commonjs module

Tags: node.js, typescript, rollup, rollupjs

I have a simple AWS Lambda function (`state-info.ts`) which I am tree-shaking with **Rollup** and it is giving me the following error:

> [!] Error: 'DB' is not exported by ../../forest-fire/abstracted-admin/lib/index.js

```
https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#name-is-not-exported-by-module
src/state-info.ts (10:9)
8: import { Lambda } from "aws-sdk";
9: import { STATES } from "./models/shared";
10: import { DB } from "abstracted-admin";
            ^
11: import { StateInfo } from "./models/StateInfo";
12: import { IApiResponse } from "./shared/ApiRetriever";
```

Now it just so happens that I wrote the module `abstracted-admin` (currently at v0.6.5 on npm) which it is complaining about and it DOES export **DB** as a named export (*and* as the default export). But for some reason Rollup is unhappy.

I've created a video walk-through of everything for full context: [video](https://www.screencast.com/t/8T1GgANrR).

For those of you who don't like video, here are the key facts/files:

[abstracted-admin/lib/index.d.ts](https://github.com/forest-fire/abstracted-admin/blob/master/lib/index.d.ts):

```
import { DB } from "./db";
export default DB;
export { DB, IFirebaseConfig, IFirebaseListener } from "./db";
```

[abstracted-admin/lib/index.js](https://github.com/forest-fire/abstracted-admin/blob/master/lib/index.js):

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const db_1 = require("./db");
exports.default = db_1.DB;
var db_2 = require("./db");
exports.DB = db_2.DB;
```

and from within the [`abstracted-admin/package.json`](https://github.com/forest-fire/abstracted-admin/blob/master/package.json):

```
{
  ...
  "files": ["lib"],
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "typings": "lib/index.d.ts",
}
```

[`state-info.ts`](https://gist.github.com/ksnyde/3271d396a6d70ea8217434c06d505fe0) (aka, the file being rolled up):

```
import {
  IDictionary,
  AWSGatewayCallback,
  IAWSGatewayRequest,
  IAWSGatewayResponse
} from "common-types";
import GetStateInfo from "./vote-smart/get-state-info";
import { Lambda } from "aws-sdk";
import { STATES } from "./models/shared";
import { DB } from "abstracted-admin";
import { StateInfo } from "./models/StateInfo";
import { IApiResponse } from "./shared/ApiRetriever";
/** ... */
```

Meanwhile my rollup config is:

```
import cjs from "rollup-plugin-commonjs";
import resolve from "rollup-plugin-node-resolve";
import json from "rollup-plugin-json";
import ts from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import globals from "rollup-plugin-node-globals";

export default {
  input: "src/state-info.ts",
  output: {
    file: "lib/state-info-rolled.js",
    format: "cjs"
  },
  external: ["aws-sdk"],
  plugins: [
    globals(),
    json(),
    cjs({
      include: "node_modules/**",
      exclude: ["node_modules/aws-sdk/**"]
    }),
    ts(),
    resolve({
      jsnext: true,
      main: true,
      browser: false,
      preferBuiltins: false,
      extensions: [".js", ".json"]
    })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe Rollup expects the below in this situation:

```
import admin from "abstracted-admin";
const { DB } = admin;
```

It's different from Webpack's behavior and has caught me a few times.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense to me ... the named export is “DB” and I also export a default export too (same export as DB named export). So in your example `import admin from “abstracted-admin”;` “admin” would be equivalent to the named DB export.

Comment: In the video you can see that the vs-code’s linter is clear about the existence of this named export

Comment: I can't comment on what VS Code is seeing but Rollup is a bit particular about this, mainly due to limitations of CommonJS: https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#name-is-not-exported-by-module

Comment: Yeah I looked at that section of the wiki but I am author to both ends of the dependency graph so I’ve ensured that the structure is good as it can be with commonjs.

Comment: Not really sure about what rollup is failing, but you may want to try `namedExports` option: https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-commonjs#custom-named-exports

Comment: yup, I did try that but still failed ... I may try again, possibly didn’t have enough patience

Comment: There is an open bug for this at rollup, not resolved yet. https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/3011#issuecomment-516947459